# understanding how input was redirected into while construct from a file

Tags: bash

I came across a syntax for "while read" loop in a bash script

```
$> while read line; do echo $line; done < f1 # f1 is a file in my current directory
```

will print the file line by line.

my search for "while read" in the bash GNU manual https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/

came up short, and while other "tutorial sites" give some usage examples, i would still like to understand the full syntax options for this construct.

can it be used for "for" loops as well? 
something like

```
for line in read; do echo $line; done < f1
```

Comment: There is no single `while read` command: `read` is a separate command that happens to be the condition for the `while` loop here.

Comment: There are three separate things in play here: the `while` loop, the `read` command, and input redirection.

Comment: You can redirect into other command structures, the `while` loop redirection is common, but can be used for `if command; then ... fi < foo` or even a function `myfunc() { ... } < foo` although that is rarely seen.

Comment: Note that the redirection works because `while` *is* a command (albeit one with a more compicated syntax than a name followed by arguments). Like any other command, it inherits file descriptors from its caller and passes its file descriptors to its "children" (in this case, commands in the condition list or the body of the loop).

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for a `while` loop is

```
while list-1; do list-2; done
```

where `list-1` is one or more commands (usually one) and the loop continues while `list-1` is successful (return value of zero), `list-2` is the "body" of the loop.

The syntax of a `for` loop is different:

```
for name in word;  do list ; done
```

where `word` is usually a list of strings, *not* a command (although it can be hacked to use a command which returns `word`).

The purpose of a `for` loop is to iterate through `word`, the purpose of `while` is to loop while a command is successful.  They are used for different tasks.

Redirection changes a file descriptor to refer to another file or file descriptor.

`<` changes file descriptor 0 (zero), also known as `stdin`

`>` changes file descriptor 1 (one), also known as `stdout`

So `somecommand < foo` changes `stdin` to read from `foo` rather than the terminal keyboard.

`somecommand > foo` changes `stdout` to write to `foo` rather than the terminal screen (if `foo` exists it will be overwritten).

In your case `somecommand` is `while`, but it can be any other - note that not all commands read from `stdin`, yet the command syntax with `<` is still valid.

A common mistake is:

```
# WRONG!
while read < somefile
do
    ....
done
```

In that case `somecommand` is `read` and the effect is that it will read the first line of `somefile`, then proceed with the body of the loop, come back, then *read the first line of the file again*!  It will continually loop just reading the first line, since `while` has no knowledge or interest in what `read` is doing, only its return value of success or fail.  (`read` uses the variable `REPLY` if you don't specify one)

Redirection examples (`$` indicates a prompt):

```
$ cat > file1
111111
<CTRL+D>
$ cat > file2
222222
<CTRL+D>
```

`cat` reads from `stdin` if we don't specify a filename, so it reads from the keyboard.  Instead of writing to the screen we redirect to a file.  The `<CTRL+D>` indicates End-Of-File sent from the keyboard.

This redirects `stdin` to read from a file:

```
$ cat < file1
111111
```

Can you explain this?

```
$ cat < file1 file2
222222
```